# What is the equivalent data type of cloud Firestore server timestamp in swift language?

Tags: swift, firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

I've got a data model including a timestamp field `createdAt`.

```
struct Box {
    var title: String
    var createdAt: Timestamp

    var dictionary: [String : Any] {
        return [
            "title": title,
            "createdAt": createdAt
        ]
    }

// ...
```

However, I am unable to assign Firestore server timestamp. What would be the equivalent data type of cloud Firestore server timestamp in swift? Am I missing a point here?

```
let box = Box(title: title, createdAt: FieldValue.serverTimestamp());
```

Comment: Server timestamps don't really have a "data type" on the client that's meaningful.  This is true for all platforms.  They're special tokens with special meaning on the server.  In Android, you can work around this with the @ServerTimestamp annotation on a Date field to serialize, but I'm not sure swift has a similar solution.

Comment: @DougStevenson That's true. At the moment, the only solution I've found so far is to define as `var createdAt: NSObject`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When you read back the `Timestamp` from `Firestore`, you can convert it to a `Date` object:

```
if let timestamp = data["createdAt"] as? Timestamp {
    let date = timestamp.dateValue()
}
```

---

```
/** Returns a new NSDate corresponding to this timestamp. This may lose precision. */
- (NSDate *)dateValue;
```

The `Timestamp` is an `FIRTimestamp` object that returns like this:

`FIRTimestamp: seconds=1525802726 nanoseconds=169000000>`

After conversion with `.dateValue()`:

`2018-05-08 18:05:26 +0000`

Comment: Thanks you. This is probably the possible solution for now.

Comment: @VahidHallaji. Did you work out a solution to your actual question. I have a createdAt: Timestamp? var in a IDRequest struct and when i create an instance of the struct i want to assign its value as FieldValue.serverTimestamp but compiler complaining the types dont match. The accepted answer is more about coming back the other way ie converting the actual timestamp back to a date object which is not what I’m trying to do